# Profile change is not working with gradle in jhipster 7

Tags: java, gradle, jhipster

Changing profiles doesn't work in an app generated with jhipster (v7.3 & 7.4) and gradle. I followed [this](https://www.jhipster.tech/profiles/). When I run from command-line `gradlew -Pprod`, the app always starts in dev profile:

```
No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: dev,api-docs
```

I think something broke in the generators as nobody is providing the `spring.profiles.active` property. I miss `it.replace('#spring.profiles.active#', profiles)}` in the *profile_prod.gradle* file that I saw in previous releases. I added it, now *application.yml* in *build* folder contains `spring: profiles: active: prod`, but the app keeps defaulting to dev.

This is my **profile_prod.gradle**:

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation "com.h2database:h2"
}
def profiles = "prod"
if (project.hasProperty("no-liquibase")) {
    profiles += ",no-liquibase"
}
if (project.hasProperty("api-docs")) {
    profiles += ",api-docs"
}
springBoot {
    buildInfo()
}
bootRun {
    args = []
}
processResources {
    println 'I'm running -Pprod!'
    inputs.property('version', version)
    inputs.property('springProfiles', profiles)
    filesMatching("**/application.yml") {
        filter {
            it.replace("#project.version#", version)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This seems like a bug, I opened an [issue](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/17134), meanwhile this **workaround** works:

1. In profile_prod.gradle, add to the processResources config: `filter { it.replace('#spring.profiles.active#', profiles) }`
2. Remove or comment *bootstrap.yml* file, it has an empty spring.profiles.active that overwrites the previous replacement.